# How do I limit the number of characters entered via cin?

Tags: c++

I wish to limit the number of characters that the user can enter, using `cin`. I might wish to limit it to two characters, for instance. How might I do this?

My code looks like this:

```
cin >> var;
```

Comment: Michael, why'd you remove the code snippet showing that Meni is using `operator>>` (as opposed to `readline`, `read`, etc)?

Comment: @Ben, I didn't believe it was relevant, given that he's already specified that he's using `cin`. If you think it's helpful, though, I'll add it back in.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `setw()`

```
 cin >> setw(2) >> var;
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setw/

> Sets the number of characters to be used as the field width for the
>   next insertion operation.

Working example provided by @chris: http://ideone.com/R35NN

Comment: @Robᵩ, this works with input operations. I remember the Deitel book uses it in the operator overloading chapter to input a phone number.

Comment: I'm wrong. Mea cupla. My only excuse is that I listened to the [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setw/) siren song. [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) has a better reference for this.

Comment: It didn't work see my code:                                              #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int var;
  cin >> setw(2) >> var;
  cout<<var;
}

Comment: @Meni, I think you'll have to just input the two characters and convert the result to an int. You can use a `stringstream`, `stoi`, etc for that.

Comment: Just as a side note: it seems that setw will not have the desired effect when the variable that we read to is an integer. E.g. you can setw to 4 and still enter 12345 successfully.

Comment: @Tomek I agree with you on this. The same is applicable for the            cout<<setw(5)<<"Hi How Are you"<<endl. This will print "Hi How Are you?" rather than "Hi Ho".

Answer (score 2):

hmm you could make 'var' a character array and use a while loop to read input until the array was full maybe?

```
char var[somenumber + 1];
int count = 0;

while(count < somenumber){
  cin >> var[count];
  count++;
}

var [somenumber] = '\0';
```